# setcookie path url doesn't work in PHP?

Tags: php, cookies, subdomain, setcookie

When the following code is called from `/foo/controllers/`:

```
setcookie(
    "email", $email, time() + 100 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30, 
    "/foo/", "bar.com", false
);
```

It gets value (copied from FireBug):

```
# line-breaks added for aesthetics
email=stackoverflowuser95%40gmail.com; 
    expires=Sun, 24 Jan 2021 06:25:33 GMT; 
    path=/foo/controllers/; domain=bar.com
```

How do I set it so that the cookie is valid for `/foo/controllers/` and `/foo/views/`?

Comment: Strange. Have you tried deleting the cookie? Could it be from a previous attempt that didn't have the `/foo` setting?

Comment: Yes, have tried deleting all my cookies.